# Swashbuckle in .NET Core - Set string parameter to be required

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to find a way to set a string parameter to be required on a ASP.NET Core Api project but haven't been able to figure it out. My assumption was just adding the DataAnnotation of [Required] would work, but this is not the case.

How does one get Swagger to realize a query string parameter of type string is required?

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json", Type = typeof(IEnumerable<string>))]
[SwaggerOperation(operationId: "ListStuff")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public IActionResult ListStuff(int id, [Required]string auditId)
{
    ...
}
```

With above code, the required flag is still false in the Swagger.json file:

```
{
  "name":"auditId",
  "in":"query",
  "required":false,
  "type":"string"
}
```

Comment: Strange that should work without the Required... what version of swashbuckle do you have?

Comment: That's what I thought too from reading some github threads. Everything should default to required unless specifically set as nullable? Unfortunately I'm seeing the complete opposite. 

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v1.0.0

Comment: Aaa you are using ***Swashbuckle.AspNetCore*** very likely a bug you should report it: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues

Comment: Thanks. Bug filed.
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/480

Comment: Shouldn't you add the attribute `[FromRoute]` for it to be required?